# Types of questions and questioning "ordinality"

Tags: grammar

I would like to know if there is a system for classifying the *types* of questions that can be asked in languages. In other words, how are sentences that query the why, where, what, who, when, and how classified? I guess *whence*, *whither*, etc. also belong in that list.

Additionally, what is the term for questions that [query "ordinality"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13662/how-should-i-phrase-a-question-that-must-be-answered-with-an-ordinal-number-e-g)? For example,

> Q: [What number] president was George Washington?
>
> A: The first.
>
> Q: [What number] son of your father are you?
>
> A: The second.

AFAIK, there is no construct to ask such a question in English. But there is in languages belonging to other families.

Are there any references on the distribution of these question types across languages?

Comment: Didn't you just create a construction that asks that question?

Comment: @GastonÜmlaut That doesn't really work in English. It might sound plausible in this case since presidents are commonly numbered. Please see the linked question on english.se. In the meantime, I will try to come up with a more convincing example :)

Comment: Don't forget yes/no questions :)

Comment: @GastonÜmlaut I have added the additional example of "Q: [What number] of your father's sons are you?". Based on [this page](http://www.teachingenglish.org.uk/blogs/vlnraojagatha/howmanieth-son-are-you-your-father) it appears that such a construct exists in an Indic language, possibly Telugu.

Comment: In French, one can ask 'le combientième', or the little obsolete form 'le quantième', so as to introduce the question about 'what number' in a ordinal context.

Comment: I was just making the point that there's no problem asking this question in English even though there's no specific morphosyntactic structure for it. Every language has various 'gaps' of this kind that require filling with circumlocutions.

Comment: In Czech, there is a simple and common word for that: [kolikátý](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/kolik%C3%A1t%C3%BD).

Comment: @Mormegil Interesting. Thanks! I also found the [Dutch equivalent](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hoeveelste). Thanks to StephaneRolland as well for [combientième](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/combienti%C3%A8me).

Comment: @GastonÜmlaut Thanks. But surely the types of questions are classified somehow or the other. The number of gaps can only be finite.

Comment: I'm not aware of any such classification of wh-questions (the term for these kinds of questions, also known as 'content questions'), but that doesn't mean such work hasn't been done. My impression is that that's because the set of wh-questions in any language is highly restricted.